Hodge filtration vs Hodge structure on algebraic de Rham cohomology
I have a basic question on the relation between the definitions of the Hodge structure on the algebraic de Rham of a smooth proper scheme defined over a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and the Hodge structure on its algebraic de Rham cohomology.
Let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme defined over a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, denoted $k$.
The Hodge filtration is defined via $\mathcal{F}^pH^i_{\text{dR}}(X/k) := \text{Im}(H^i(X, \Omega^{\bullet\ge p})\longrightarrow H^i(X, \Omega^{\bullet})$, which implies that it is given by a $k$-vector subspace of $H^i_{\text{dR}}(X/k)$.
The Hodge structure is the data of a decreasing filtration on the complexification of $H^i_{\text{dR}}(X/k)$, i.e. on $H^i_{\text{dR}}(X/k)\otimes \mathbb{C}$.
Is the Hodge structure the same as the complexification of the Hodge filtration?

The term "Hodge structure" is often used for more data than this, i.e. also the group $H^i(X/\mathbb C,\mathbb Z)$ and the isomorphism $H^i(X/\mathbb C, \mathbb Z)\otimes \mathbb C \cong H^i_{dR}(X/\mathbb C)$, but other than that, yes.

Thanks Professor Sawin!

Depending on how you define the Hodge structure, proving this might require some combination of flat base change, GAGA, and Hodge theory.
